# How to get Listbox item from the listbox wpf

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollviewer, selecteditem

I want to scroll the listbox which is placed inside the srollviewer according to its selection.

```
 ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)(lbTrack.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lbTrack.Items.CurrentItem));

       // ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)(lbTrack.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lbTrack.SelectedItem));
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.BringIntoView();
        }
```

But it giving null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
if (listView.SelectedItem != null)
{
   listView.ScrollIntoView(listView.SelectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
  {
      item.BringToView();
   }, DispatcherPriority.Normal, null);
```